# How to create a shared timer decreasing after first initialization

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, countdowntimer

I have a multi threaded java application in which each thread tries to get a db connection from pool. If connection is not available then wait for 5 minutes till three attempts and fail if connection not created in three attempts.

What I want now is to create some shared decreasing timer initialized with value 5 minutes. This timer will start when first connection failure occurs and thread will go into wait state for 5 minutes. Now for further threads, if connection failure occurs and timer is already started then pick current value of timer and go to wait state till the current value of timer. Now whenever thread will wake up, it will re-try connection and re-set the timer to 5 minutes more if failed again.

Is there any existing solution for this available.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: As I mentioned, currently I am just putting 5 minutes wait for for each thread if failure to get connection. So if thread 1 get failure and go into 5 minutes wait and thread 2 come after three minutes and still db failure then will go into 5 minutes wait while it should go into 2 minutes wait

Answer (score 1):

use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as a shared timer and store the timestamp of the last check in a shared `static final AtomicLong` which you could `getAndSet` or `getAndUpdate` on each check and compare the read value with the current time time, calculate if it's within the 5 minute or not.